# How to add script tag attributes using assets pipeline / sprockets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

Is there a way to add additional script tag attributes when using the rails assets pipeline (sprockets)?

Say I have a manifest file that sends down a JS script like so:

```
//= someScript.js
```

Is there a way to change this so that the resulting script tag has, e.g., a crossorigin attribute, like so:

```
<script src="/assets/someScript.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Seems like this would be necessary or useful from time to time...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since assets pipeline squashes all enlisted files into a single `application.js`, the option can't be provided for a single file in `application.js`

But, you can provide this option to the whole `application.js` file:

```
javascript_include_tag "application", crossorigin: "anonymous"
```

Or, include your `someScript.js` separately using `crossorigin` option